# How to fix error message when adding SQS redrive policy for deadletter queue created using for_each

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sqs, terraform-provider-aws

I want terraform to associate my SQS Management Event with my DLQ management event and i want the same thing done with SQS Data Event and DLQ Data Event.I am getting error messages when i run apply on my code below.please I need some help.

```
.tfvars

sqs_queue_names = ["CloudTrail_SQS_Management_Event", "CloudTrail_SQS_Data_Event"]

dead_queue_names = ["CloudTrail_DLQ_Management_Event", "CloudTrail_DLQ_Data_Event"]
```

```
main.tf

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "CloudTrail_SQS"{

    for_each                   = var.sqs_queue_names
    name                       = each.value
    redrive_policy = jsonencode({
        deadLetterTargetArn    = values(aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ)[*].arn
        maxReceiveCount        = var.max_receive_count
    })

    tags = var.default_tags
    
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ"{

    for_each                   = var.dead_queue_names
    name                       = each.value
   
    tags = var.default_tags
}
```

```
Error: error creating SQS Queue (CloudTrail_SQS_Management_Event): InvalidParameterValue: Value {"deadLetterTargetArn":["arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456789012:CloudTrail_DLQ_Data_Event","arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456789012:CloudTrail_DLQ_Management_Event"],"maxReceiveCount":10} for parameter RedrivePolicy is invalid. Reason: Invalid value for deadLetterTargetArn.
│       status code: 400, request id: 9663b896-d86f-569e-92e2-e17152c2db26
│ 
│   with aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS["CloudTrail_SQS_Management_Event"],
│   on main.tf line 5, in resource "aws_sqs_queue" "CloudTrail_SQS":
│    5: resource "aws_sqs_queue" "CloudTrail_SQS"{
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: error creating SQS Queue (CloudTrail_SQS_Data_Event): InvalidParameterValue: Value {"deadLetterTargetArn":["arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456789012:CloudTrail_DLQ_Data_Event","arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456789012:CloudTrail_DLQ_Management_Event"],"maxReceiveCount":10} for parameter RedrivePolicy is invalid. Reason: Invalid value for deadLetterTargetArn.
│       status code: 400, request id: 88b8e4c5-1d50-5559-92f8-bd2297fd231f
│ 
│   with aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS["CloudTrail_SQS_Data_Event"],
│   on main.tf line 5, in resource "aws_sqs_queue" "CloudTrail_SQS":
│    5: resource "aws_sqs_queue" "CloudTrail_SQS"{
```

Comment: You can only specify one target arn, you are trying to pass multiple.

Comment: I have 2 SQS and 2 Deadletter queue.How can I specify each SQS created for each DeadLetter queue created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways of doing this. One way would be as follows:

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "CloudTrail_SQS"{

    for_each                   = {for idx, val in var.sqs_queue_names: idx => val}
    name                       = each.value
    redrive_policy = jsonencode({
        deadLetterTargetArn    = values(aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ)[each.key].arn
        maxReceiveCount        = var.max_receive_count
    })

    tags = var.default_tags   
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ"{

    for_each                   = toset(var.dead_queue_names)
    name                       = each.value
   
    tags = var.default_tags
}
```

In the above, you create `index` variable as key for `for_each` and use that to reference DLQ values.

Comment: when I configured it the way you suggested,i got this . Error: Cycle: aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS["CloudTrail_SQS_Data_Event"], aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS["CloudTrail_SQS_Management_Event"]

Comment: @bibi The answer was updated

Comment: thanks for updating the answer but i received the same error,Do i need to change my variable from set(string) to list(string)

Comment: @bibi Check exactly my answer. Probably you did not copy it all. The answer works.

Comment: thanks for response,I just copied the exact code and now I am getting different error message------- Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on main.tf line 15, in resource "aws_sqs_queue" "CloudTrail_SQS":
│   15:         deadLetterTargetArn    = values(aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ)[each.key].arn
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ is object with 2 attributes
│     │ each.key is "CloudTrail_SQS_Management_Event"
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: a
│ number is required.

Comment: @bibi This means that your code in question is different then what you use. Sadly, I don't know what is your real code. My answer i based on  what you posted. I would suggest making new question for the new error with new code example.

Comment: thank you,I will make a new question right away

Comment: @bibi No problem. If my answer was helpful to overcome the original issue reported, it's acceptance would be appreciated.